# Sort Nested HashMap By Inner Value

Tags: java

I am trying to sort a nested HashMap,
`HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> myMap = new HashMap<>()`, by a specific value in the inner HashMap. 
The program reads a delimited file that contains the following values:

000001014|A||Harvey|T|Dent|05/27/1991|0902|000001014|05/27/1991|01/01/3000|
000001388|A||Tony|K|Stark|09/19/1992|0054|000001388|09/19/1992|01/01/3000|
000001395|A||Steve|C|Rogers|10/26/1992|7402|000001395|10/26/1992|01/01/3000| 000001396|A||Peter|P|Parker|11/02/1992|1002|000001396|11/02/1992|01/01/3000| 000011148|I||Drax|T|Destroyer|02/17/1992|7005|000011148|02/17/1992|01/01/3000|  000011141|A||Rocket|M|Raccoon|02/10/1992|7170|000011141|02/10/1992|01/01/3000|000001404|A||Natasha||Romanoff|12/28/1992|7240|00001404|12/28/1992|01/01/3000| 000001442|A||Bruce|T|Banner|10/06/1993|7012|000001442|10/06/1993|01/01/3000|
000001450|A||Scott|L|Lang|11/29/1993|0002|000001450|11/29/1993|01/01/3000|  000001486|A||Thor|J|Odinson|07/04/1994|0002|000001486|07/04/1994|01/01/3000|

I chose a Nested HashMap so that each line in the file has its own key and then each element in each line has a key. For example myMap.get(0).get(7) returns 0902, myMap.get(1).get(7) returns 0054, myMap.get(2).get(7) returns 7402. But the problem is that sorting the HashMap by the nested HashMap value has been a real humdinger. So, what I am trying to accomplish is to sort the whole HashMap by the 7th element in the inner map.

Should I sort myMap the old fashion way using a nested loops and binary sort or insertion sort? How do I tackle this problem?

```
private static Path directory() {
    File home = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory();
    String path = home.getAbsolutePath();
    Path dir;
    //For reference Directory 
    C:\Users\PC_USER_NAME\Desktop\Work\Person\Employees.txt
    if(getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")) {//specify your 
        directory Windows
        dir = Paths.get(path + File.separator + "Work" + File.separator + "Person");
    } else {//Specify your directory Mac
        dir = Paths.get(File.separator + "Users" + File.separator + 
        getProperty("user.name") + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator + "Work" + File.separator + "Person");
    }
    return dir;
}

private static void readFile() {
    HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Integer, String> inner = new HashMap<>();
    BufferedReader reader;
    String line;
    int count = 0;
    try {
        File dir = new File(directory().toString());
        File[] files = dir.listFiles((File pathname) -> 
        pathname.getName().startsWith("Employees"));
        File lastModifiedFile = files[0];

        for (File file : files) {
            if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < file.lastModified()) {
                lastModifiedFile = file;
            }
        }

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(lastModifiedFile));
        //Skips the header.
        reader.readLine();
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] keyValue = line.split("\\|");

            for (int i = 0; i < keyValue.length; i++) {
                inner.put(i, keyValue[i]);
            }
            myMap.put(count, inner);
            count++;
            inner = new HashMap<>();
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    sort(myMap);
}

private static void sort(HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> myMap) {
    Set<Entry<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>>> sorted = 
    myMap.entrySet();

    for(Entry<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> entry : sorted) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " ==> " +   entry.getValue().get(7));
    }
    //Won't add this method code for brevity sake   
    writeFile();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all - what does it mean to *sort a HashMap*? To print sorted values as I guess what does mean you won't be sorting `Map` itself, but some kind of collection of it's values

Second thing - why do you want to keep such data in a `Map`? It sounds like really bad idea, and you just spotted the first argument why

For me you should create some kind of `Row` class like

```
public class Row {
    private List<String> items; // for '|' splitted values in a row, maybe it should be even String[]?

    ...
}
```

and keep your whole file as a `List<Row>`. Then you can create your own [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or even make `Row` implements `Comparable`

```
public class Row implements Comparable<Row>{
    private List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Row that) {
        return this.items.get(8).compareTo(that.items.get(7));
    }
}
```

Now you can easily sort the file using `Collections.sort()` util

Please notice that implementing `Comparator` allow you to create many versions of them (like `SortBy6thComparator`, `SortBy7thComparator`, `SortBy8thComparator`...). You just need to use then another version of `sort` method:

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. I was thinking that I would need to build my own Comparator but was unsure if that was the right way to go. Again, thank you for your advice.

Comment: Please don't call the class `Row`. If it is a file of employees, maybe call the class ... `Employee`? Please.